# Does each IntentService get its own background thread?

Tags: android

Apparently, all [`AsyncTask`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html)s share one thread:

> Starting with HONEYCOMB, tasks are executed on a single thread to avoid common application errors caused by parallel execution.

An [`IntentService`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/IntentService.html) gets one thread and handles each `Intent` in turn:

> All requests are handled on a single worker thread -- they may take as long as necessary (and will not block the application's main loop), but only one request will be processed at a time.

But if I have multiple `IntentService`s, does each get its own thread? Or does Android just use one thread that all `IntentService`s share?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Apparently, all AsyncTasks share one thread:

By default, yes. Use `executeOnExecutor()` to opt into a thread pool. In [the documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html), the next paragraph after your quoted one is:

> If you truly want parallel execution, you can invoke executeOnExecutor(java.util.concurrent.Executor, Object[]) with THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR.

> But if I have multiple IntentServices, does each get its own thread?

Yes. The [source code to `IntentService`](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/master/core/java/android/app/IntentService.java) shows that it creates its own `HandlerThread` in `onCreate()`.